# Installing Anaconda on WSL for Ubuntu

Tags: anaconda, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, anaconda3, python-3.11

I have WSL(windows subsystem linux) ubuntu on windows 10. I want to install Anaconda. In terminal I entered "bash Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-x86_64.sh". During installation "[222] Failed to execute script entry_point" appeared. I don't know what should I do now. I made following steps and I mentioned errors. I don't know what to do now.

1. Running "bash Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-x86_64.sh" again and I got "ERROR: File or directory already exists: '/home/nazanin/anaconda3'
   If you want to update an existing installation, use the -u option."
2. shasum -a 256 /home/nazanin/Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-x86_64.sh. But the result was "e7ecbccbc197ebd7e1f211c59df2e37bc6959d081f2235d387e08c9026666acd  /home/nazanin/Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-x86_64.sh". Which is not accurate according to "https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/hashes/Anaconda3-2022.10-Windows-x86_64.exe-hash/".
3. dir command; Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-x86_64.sh exists

Comment: (2) looks like shasum on Linux, but then comparing to Windows hash. Please clarify. If hash is wrong, then redownload.

Comment: When I try to redownload it says that it already exists. Maybe I should erase it first then redownload. But I don't know how to erase.

Comment: Something like `rm Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-x86_64.sh`